# Cloudant - Lucene range search using numbers stored as text

Tags: lucene, cloudant

I have a number of documents in Cloudant, that have ID field of type string. ID can be a simple string, like "aaa", "bbb" or number stored as text, e.g. "111", "222", etc. I need to be able to full text search using the above field, but I encountered some problems.

Assuming that I have two documents, having ID="aaa" and ID="111", then searching with query:

- ID:aaa
- ID:"aaa"
- ID:[aaa TO zzz]
- ID:["aaa" TO "zzz"]

returns first document, as expected

- ID:111

returns nothing, but

- ID:"111"

returns second document, so at least there is a way to retrieve it.

Unfortunately, when searching for range:

- ID:[111 TO 999]
- ID:["111" TO "999"]

I get no results, and I have no idea what to do to get around this problem. Is there any special syntax for such case?

UPDATE:

Index function:

```
function(doc){
  if(!doc.ID) return;
  index("ID", doc.ID, { index:'not_analyzed_no_norms', store:true });
}
```

Changing index to *analyzed* doesn't help. Analyzer itself is *keyword*, but changing to *standard* doesn't help either.

UPDATE 2

Just to add some more context, because I think I missed one key point. The field I'm indexing will be searched using ranges, and both min and max values can be provided by user. So it is possible that one of them will be number stored as a string, while other will be a standard non-numeric text. For example search all document where ID >= "11" and ID <= "foo".

Assumig that database contains documents with ID "1", "5", "alpha", "beta", "gamma", this query should return "5", "alpha", "beta". Please note that "5" should actually be returned, because string "5" is greater than string "11".

Comment: Any chance you can share your Map function?

Comment: There's no map function, as this is full text index. Question is now updated, and contains index function body.

Comment: @ArekDygas can you comment on why you would want to do this kind of range query on strings? It seems to me that if sorting and querying a range was important, you'd be using numeric values.

Comment: @Raj It's hard to explain the full purpose, without providing a detailed description of the system. In short, the field I have to query over is filled by users, that can enter anything in it, be it ABCDEF, 32342, )(*^@%, or any other value. Another user might then issue command to search over this field, providing a single value (for exact match), or two values (for a range).

If I won't be able to resolve this issue, then I'll have to think on preprocessing of user entered values, but I'd like to avoid this if possible, as this might prove non-trivial.

Comment: @ArekDygas maybe your use case is more like a proximity search than a range search? Range implies finding things that lie "in between", which doesn't sound like that concept applies here. Whereas text proximity is in the sweet spot for this type of search.

Comment: @Raj This is definitely range search. When user executes a search, he wants to get either a single document matching specific string, or a number of documents having ID greater than or equal to first entered string, and less than or equal to second entered string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our team just came to a workaround solution. We managed to get proper results by adding some arbitrary character, e.g. 'a' to an upper range value, and by introducing additional search term, to exclude documents having ID  between upper range value and upper range value + 'a'.

When searching for a range

ID:[X TO Y]

actual query would be

(ID:[X TO Ya] AND -ID:{Y TO Ya])

For example, to find a documents having ID between 23 and 758, we execute

(ID:[23 TO 758a] AND -ID:{758 TO 758a]).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would suggest to use keyword analyzer, so you can control the right tokenization during both indexing and search.

```
"analyzer": "keyword",
"index": "function(doc){\n  if(!doc.ID) return;\n  index(\"ID\", doc.ID, {store:true });\n}
```

To retrieve you document with _id "111", use the following range query:

```
curl -X GET "http://.../facetrangetest/_design/ddoc/_search/f?q=ID:\[111%20TO%A\]"
```

If you use a query `q=ID:\[111%20TO%20999\]`, Cloudant search seeing numbers on both size of the range, will interpret it as NumericRangeQuery; and since your ID of "111" is a String, it will not be part of the results returned. Including a string into query [111%20TO%20A], will make Cloudant interpret it as a range query on strings.

Comment: I actually use keyword analyzer. And regarding [111 TO A] - this works, but unfortunately won't help in my case, as I won't be able to search for ranges like 2 TO 123... I thought that Cloudant should interpret range types basing on actual field type, but apparently this is not how it works...

Comment: It is not possible to interpret range types on actual field type, because it is not possible to know the field type, as both CouchDb and Apache Lucene may have different types for the same field name.

Answer (score 1):

You can get both docs returned like this:

```
q=ID:["111" TO "CCC"]
```

Here's a working live example:

https://rajsingh.cloudant.com/facetrangetest/_design/ddoc/_search/f?q=ID:[%22111%22%20TO%20%22CCC%22]

I found something quirky. It seems that range queries on strings only work if at least one of the range values is a string. Querying on `ID:["111" TO "555"]` doesn't return anything either, so maybe this is resolving to a numeric query somehow? Could be a bug.

Comment: Yes - ["111" TO "CCC"] will work, but, as noted in comment to Mayya Sharipova's answer, won't help in my case... Unfortunately I also think this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be achieved using regular expressions in queries. Something line this:

`curl -X POST "https://.../facetrangetest/_design/ddoc/_search/f"   -d '{"q":"ID:/<23-758>/"}' | jq .`

This regular expressions means to retrieve all documents with ID field from 23 to 758.   Slashes: `/` `/` are used to enclose a regular expression; the interval is enclosed inside `<>`.

Comment: I think this works for numbers only, so unfortunately it doesn't cover my needs...

Comment: Hmm. When I change query to /<1-a>/ , I get 'interval syntax error at position 4'. Enclosing text in double quotes (/<1-"a">/) doesn't help either (error at position 6). Could you please share an example query that works with strings?

Comment: +1 I just re-read my original question, and now I see the point of your answer. I updated a question a bit, but even without that update, regex interval won't really help in my case, because your query won't return document with ID "5555". For numbers it would be ok, but unfortunately for text it is not...

Comment: oh, considering that you have both numbers and strings in your field, than the only solution currently would be the one you proposed yourself. +1 for that